# Oracle CharacterSet Migration CSSCAN

Tags: database, oracle

I'm having an Oracle 10g installation on Windows, and I'm trying to upgrade to 11g installed on Oracle Linux, with a change of the character set from we8iso8859p1 to we8iso8859p15.
Before upgrading i want to run the csscan to see if data in the 10g db is ok. I'm only interested in a schema(only this will be exported), so i want to run it only on that schema. 
Can i do this? How ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`cssscan` documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch12scanner.htm#i1005939) shows that you can run it for a single user (schema), with a `USER=<schema>` parameter. Also see the [parameter section](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch12scanner.htm#i1006158). I don't have an environment set up to run this against but I seem to think ti was pretty straightforward when I last used it, just following the docs.